# Null 'key' argument error

Tags: java, charts, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using IReport 3.5.0 and my java GWT application uses the compiled .jasper file, to create a report. I'm creating the datasource in the java application and use `fillReport()` method to fill the report. It works fine, it fills the fields that I have defined both in the .jrxml and Java application.

However, I want to use those fields to create a pie chart, and it doesn't work. I give my working fields as key and value expressions for the chart, but when I run the application, it gives the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null 'key' argument.` I couldn't solve it, even when I give `$V{PAGE_COUNT}` as key expression, it always give the same 'null key' error. I'm stuck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: In what part of your report is your chart? The fields maybe out of scope.

Comment: i put it in the summary, but it gave the same error when i tried it in the detail.

Comment: Can you print the fields in the detail band?

Comment: normally, yeah. but this error causes the report to not be created of course.

Comment: could it be about its evaluation time? I tried changing it, but it made no difference

Comment: Can you post some code and the full stack trace?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same kind of issue. Basically the Pie Chart in JasperReport hates null object. The error message doesn't help very much...

Since you have already check for the key expression, check every other elements. My error was in a label expression!

If you can run your application in a IDE, put a breakpoint on "IllegalArgumentException". It will help you find the root cause. Also make sure the report recompile the jrxml every time you make a change.

Another approach would be to start with an example and modify it to fit your need little by little. You will find the culprit soon enough!

By the way, this has nothing to do with GWT since this all run on the server.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same kind of problem with iReport 3.0
I used conditionals to work with null values on key expression and value expression:

```
($F{FIELDEXPRESSION}!=null?$F{FIELDEXPRESSION}:"")

($F{FIELDVALUE}!=null?(new BigDecimal($F{FIELDVALUE})):(new BigDecimal("0")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. So used a if loop to check if there is a null value in the column i am traversing.

```
  if(result.get()==null) // result is where is stored my resultset output
 {
    dataset.setValue(count.get(j),"N/A","No Data Available");} // count refers to the number of null entries
       else dataset.setValue(count.get(j),results.get(j),results.get(j)); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am unable to comment, this might not be a full resolution. I resolved my issue by checking the data types of the fields.

Where I previously had:

```
<field name="date" class="java.sql.Date"/>
```

I changed to:

```
<field name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

because my field will give me ex:"Jul 15" (FYI which I made it in my query) format type date which can't be `java.sql.Date` type.