# Cannot fix the null 'key' argument to get graph to generate

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans, graph

I have a graph that will display a comparison between quotes and invoices linked to an employee number within a certain time period. When I run the application, I get this infamous error message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null 'key' argument.
>       at org.jfree.chart.util.ParamChecks.nullNotPermitted(ParamChecks.java:65)
>       at org.jfree.data.DefaultKeyedValues.setValue(DefaultKeyedValues.java:234)
>       at org.jfree.data.DefaultKeyedValues2D.setValue(DefaultKeyedValues2D.java:341)
>       at org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset.setValue(DefaultCategoryDataset.java:262)
>       at org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset.setValue(DefaultCategoryDataset.java:278)
>       at SV_ManagerDivision.SV_ManagerEmpPerformance.monthGraph(SV_ManagerEmpPerformance.java:577)
>       at SV_ManagerDivision.SV_ManagerEmpPerformance.btnViewQIActionPerformed(SV_ManagerEmpPerformance.java:303)
>       at SV_ManagerDivision.SV_ManagerEmpPerformance.access$200(SV_ManagerEmpPerformance.java:24)
>       at SV_ManagerDivision.SV_ManagerEmpPerformance$3.actionPerformed(SV_ManagerEmpPerformance.java:159)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)

I have tried everything to fix it, even this Stack Overflow question: [Null 'key' argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447108/null-key-argument-error), but it did not help me solve the problem.

The coding for this graph to generate is:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select username, count(invoice_number) as invoiceCount, invoice_date from invoicedb where username = '" + empno + "' "
                    + "and extract(month from invoice_date) = '" + text + "' and extract(year from invoice_date) = '" + year + "'");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            DefaultCategoryDataset ddataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
            while (rs.next()) {
                ddataset.setValue(rs.getInt("invoiceCount"),
                       "invoiceCount",
                       rs.getString("username"));
            }
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("select username, count(quote_number) as quoteCount, quote_date from quotedb where username = '" + empno + "' and extract(month from quote_date) = '" + text + "'"
                    + " and extract(year from quote_date) = '"+ year +"'");
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                ddataset.setValue(rs.getInt("quoteCount"),
                       "quoteCount",
                       rs.getString("username"));
            }
```

The error appears to lie on this line:

```
ddataset.setValue(rs.getInt("invoiceCount"),
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there another way to fix this error?

Comment: SQL Injection detected. Use parameter binding.

Comment: @lad2025 pardon my ignorance but how do I do that?

Comment: [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html: stop using concatenation. Use query parameters. If you want help with your error, post the exact and complete stack trace of the exception. Tell us which line of code it refers to.

Comment: @JBNizet The stack trace is a very long list of errors that pertain to generated lines of code in my application. I did specify which line of code of mine it was referring to in my question

Comment: Then at least show the 10 first lines of the stack trace. Although I don't see what's so hard about posting it all. You don't need to type it. Just copy and paste it. It's important you post it, because it tells exactly what's wrong and where. You're asking this question because you don't know how to read the stack trace.

Comment: @JBNizet The reason why I don't post all or more of it is because whenever I do most of the users just moan about it, saying it's not minimal and such and vote me down. But I will put an update of the error though for you to see

Comment: I've never see anyone complaining about the presence of a stack trace here. And I'm here often. What I see is people complaining about irrelevant code being posted. But that's not the same thing at all. When asking about an error, the error stack trace is never irrelevant.

Comment: @JBNizet Well none the less, I have posted the first ten lines of the stack trace in my question now as you suggested

Comment: @lad2025 The link you posted seems helpful but I am uncertain which of those methods to actually use. I tried the `setNull` and the syntax just indicated errors on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the stack trace, I now know that you're calling the [following method](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/DefaultCategoryDataset.html#setValue-double-java.lang.Comparable-java.lang.Comparable-):

I can thus read its documentation and see that it says:

> Parameters:
>
> ```
> value - the value.
> rowKey - the row key (null not permitted).
> columnKey - the column key (null not permitted).
> ```

The message of the exception says:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null 'key' argument. at

We can thus safely assume that one of the arguments passed to the method (`rowKey` or `columnKey`) is null.

`rowKey` is the literal string `"quoteCount"`. So it's obviously not null.

`columnKey` is `rs.getString("username")`. So that means that one of the rows returned by your query has a null `username`.

Fix your data, or filter out the rows that have a null `username`.

Comment: Okay I made some changes based on what you said and that has fixed the null key error. But now Y-axis values are displayed as exponential values, the texts on the X-axis are appearing as "0" instead of the specified text and the bars are appearing as lines in the center of the graph

Comment: Try to reason about why that happens. And if you're stuck, ask another question, saying you're using JFreechart, showing how you create your graph, what you expect to happen and what happens instead.

Comment: Okay I will do that. But at least that error has stopped coming up, thanks.